# Is it possible that 3 IP addresses from the same network come from different countries?

Tags: geolocation, geoip2

https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-demo shows 3 different countries for  5.62.61.176, 5.62.61.196 and 5.62.61.172. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Maxmind has incorrect results for 3 IP addresses. In this case, I performed network traceroute to determine the location of Avast servers.

You can see that 5.62.62.176 is located in UK. Meanwhile 5.62.61.196 and 5.62.61.172 are located in CZ.

Below are the traceroute reports and geolocation results from [IP2Location](https://www.ip2location.com/demo).

**Case 1) 5.62.62.176**
Reference: https://www.locaping.com/result/pjsaQmv0

%>traceroute to 5.62.62.176 (5.62.62.176), 20 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 176.67.168.129 (176.67.168.129) 1.225 ms 1.263 ms 1.242 ms
2 te0-3-1-3.nr51.b022764-0.par05.atlas.cogentco.com (149.6.166.145) 0.643 ms 0.594 ms 0.868 ms
3 be3587.rcr21.par05.atlas.cogentco.com (154.25.5.125) 1.118 ms 1.050 ms 1.065 ms
4 be3625.ccr41.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.0.165) 1.482 ms be3626.ccr42.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.1.45) 1.327 ms be3625.ccr41.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.0.165) 1.379 ms
5 be12497.ccr41.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.56.129) 8.949 ms be12489.ccr42.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.57.69) 8.961 ms 8.977 ms
6 be2871.ccr21.lon01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.58.186) 9.121 ms 8.980 ms be2868.ccr21.lon01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.57.154) 8.873 ms
7 be2207.rcr21.b015589-1.lon01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.51.158) 9.084 ms 9.065 ms 9.351 ms
8 149.14.8.78 (149.14.8.78) 9.485 ms 9.734 ms 9.665 ms
9 border3.xe-1-1-0-bbnet2.lon003.pnap.net (212.118.240.116) 9.820 ms 8.881 ms border3.xe-0-1-0-bbnet1.lon003.pnap.net (212.118.240.52) 8.990 ms
10 avast-13.lon007.pnap.net (212.118.253.130) 14.051 ms 14.241 ms 14.433 ms

[image]

**Case 2) 5.62.61.196**
Reference: https://www.locaping.com/result/LRlnuyBU

%> traceroute 5.62.61.196 traceroute to 5.62.61.196 (5.62.61.196), 20 hops max, 60 byte packets 1 176.67.168.129 (176.67.168.129) 0.724 ms
0.679 ms 0.708 ms 2 te0-3-1-3.nr51.b022764-0.par05.atlas.cogentco.com (149.6.166.145) 0.555 ms 0.562 ms 0.877 ms 3 be3587.rcr21.par05.atlas.cogentco.com (154.25.5.125) 1.105 ms 1.078 ms
1.184 ms 4 be3625.ccr41.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.0.165) 1.380 ms be3626.ccr42.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.1.45) 1.341 ms be3625.ccr41.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.0.165) 1.280 ms 5 be3183.ccr31.par04.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.66) 1.668 ms be3184.ccr31.par04.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.158) 1.918 ms be3183.ccr31.par04.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.66) 1.559 ms 6 * * * 7 * * * 8 * * * 9 AVAST-SOFTW.bear1.Prague1.Level3.net (212.162.11.86)
35.346 ms AVAST-SOFTW.bear1.Prague1.Level3.net (212.162.8.146) 35.510 ms AVAST-SOFTW.bear1.Prague1.Level3.net (212.162.11.82) 35.157 ms 10 *
* *
[image]

**Case 3) 5.62.61.172**
Reference: https://www.locaping.com/result/gPfLiKV8

%> traceroute 5.62.61.172 traceroute to 5.62.61.172 (5.62.61.172), 20 hops max, 60 byte packets 1 176.67.168.129 (176.67.168.129) 0.515 ms
0.525 ms 0.455 ms 2 te0-3-1-3.nr51.b022764-0.par05.atlas.cogentco.com (149.6.166.145) 0.738 ms 0.680 ms 0.626 ms 3 be3587.rcr21.par05.atlas.cogentco.com (154.25.5.125) 1.068 ms 1.026 ms
1.108 ms 4 be3625.ccr41.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.0.165) 1.033 ms 1.430 ms 1.364 ms 5 be3183.ccr31.par04.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.66) 1.588 ms 1.987 ms 1.909 ms 6 * * * 7 * * * 8 * * * 9 AVAST-SOFTW.bear1.Prague1.Level3.net (212.162.11.86) 35.133 ms AVAST-SOFTW.bear1.Prague1.Level3.net (212.162.8.146) 35.527 ms AVAST-SOFTW.bear1.Prague1.Level3.net (212.162.11.86) 35.069 ms 10 * *
*
[image]